# Including multiple of the same ad unit on a single page

Tags: google-ad-manager

We're looking to increase the number of available impressions on each page on our site and rather than create a ton of ad units, I was under the impression I could simply include the same ad unit as many times as I want, but most are returning completely empty even though they should fill with at least house ads.

Looking in the code, the iframes that the ads load in look basically like this:

`<iframe id="google_ads_iframe_/XXXXXXX/ros_leaderboard_4" name="google_ads_iframe_/79780199/ros_leaderboard_4" title="3rd party ad content" width="728" height="90" scrolling="no" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" frameborder="0" role="region" aria-label="Advertisement" tabindex="0" style="border: 0px; vertical-align: bottom;" data-google-container-id="5" data-load-complete="true"></iframe>`

and

`<iframe id="google_ads_iframe_/79780199/ros_leaderboard_1" name="google_ads_iframe_/XXXXXXX/ros_leaderboard_1" title="3rd party ad content" width="728" height="90" scrolling="no" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" frameborder="0" role="region" aria-label="Advertisement" tabindex="0" style="border: 0px; vertical-align: bottom;" data-google-container-id="5" data-load-complete="true"></iframe>`

(just showing two for an example and I changed our ad account ID to XXXXXX just in case but for here only)

The actual code for the ad unit is `ros_leaderboard` in this example and the code we have on the site appends the extra underscore and number so that there are different `div` ids.

Is this the completely wrong way to implement this? Should I have one unique ad unit for each ad slot I want to appear on the page? I can't see any pattern where the ads choose to fill, so I know conceptually this works since more than one definitely always fills, but never all of them.

Thanks

Comment: could you share the code in which you define the ad slots  ?

Comment: you also might be interested in this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67171767/how-do-i-setup-dfp-gpt-ad-slot-for-multiple-ad-placements-on-same-page/67196914#67196914 => take a look a the comments below the answer....